# Get dropdown list selected text and selected value while submiting in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to get Drop down list with Selected Text and Selected Value while submitting the form in ASP.Net MVC

If there's any solution please let me know it.

Comment: At least provide some code of your form containing the selecLlist and the method that is saving the data. Then we are helping you if there is any problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Regex syntax for drop down list, then while posting the form the selected value will also be submitted to your action along with other details.

Comment: No I am not using regex syntax for drop down list

Comment: Please edit the relevant code in the question, so that we can guide you accordingly.